# How to reduce bitmap quality without affecting it's size

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

is there a way i can compress an image of 115kb to be 4kb in android **Without affecting it size?**. just reducing it quality?

i only know of using

- BitmapFactory.Options  which reduces both size and quality
- Bitmap.compress which does not give you options for specifying size in bytes.

public Bitmap compressImage(String imagePath) {

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imagePath),null, options);


  options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imagePath),null, options);

  return bmp;
}



public  int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
  final int height = options.outHeight;
  final int width = options.outWidth;
  int inSampleSize = 1;

  if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
  }
  final float totalPixels = width * height;
  final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

  while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
    inSampleSize++;
  }

  return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Why you need this? to avoid OOME ? it will not help! ... it doesn't matter if file from which Bitmap is decoded has 4KB or 1MB ... **the Bitmap object will take the same amount of memory depending only on Bitmap width and height and pixel format**

Comment: @Selvin        i don't need this to avoid OOME. actually am trying to implement a image sharing app like whatsapp where a user will see how the image looks like before downloading. therefore am thinking of sending an image with same dimensions as original but low quality to the user through googles GCM which limits data load to 4kb :(

Comment: there is no way other like trying `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, q)` with different `q` value ... but you could try to split file into 4kb pices ... or use Google drive API(or any other could storage) and send only the link

Comment: @Selvin        if i use this method, i can't tell that image bytes exceed 4kb. and if they do and i send them through google GCM, i get error MessageTooBig

Comment: huh?  why ... `for(int q = 100; q > 0; q--) {OutputStream out = getOutputFromFile(file);bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, q, out); if(checkFileSize(file) < 4000) {sendFile(file); break;}}` ... of course it is not optimal way (it's more like brute force) also it may take a long time...

Comment: @Selvin        i have the same idea as yours but isn't it going to be CPU expensive?. i was asking myself if there is another better way to do it that why i posted this question but sadly somebody downvoted me:(

Comment: *isn't it going to be CPU expensive?* yes, it will ... but you could use some better algorith like in the "finding the number game" check fx for q=65 file size is smaller then 4kb and above is bigger ...  so you would check 100, 50, 75, 63, 69, ...

Comment: @Selvin  ok. i have also read your profile page and got your message.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understand what are you doing. compressing 1mb image (and keeping dimensions the same!) down to 4KiB is downright impossible. http://imgur.com/ap57rNJ even if by any miracle you manage to compress it that way, the resulting image will be unrecognizable

Comment: @poss       actually, the image is 115 kb  which i want to reduce to 4kb. i've edited my question. :)

Comment: You should send over GCM at most the link to your image. GCM was not created for this. Afterwards you can decode the image easily in Android if you have the URL. If the user has to decide afterwards about the download, just hold two folders, original and compressed (with a fixed compression level)

Comment: @RaduIonescu   but i want the user to first see how the image looks like before downloading it. if i send him the link, he will download the entire image. so as i said, before he download it, i want to show him how it looks like. so my idea was to send some bytes + image link through GCM. are you having a clue of my idea Radu?

Comment: @Selvin        you did not give a reason for downvoting questions like **I want develop application like xxxxx**. please do. :)

Comment: You want to send the user `myPic.png`. You send through GCM the link `http://example.com/small/myPic.png`, download it in your application for displaying purposes and if the user wants to have the full image download it from `http://example.com/large/myPic.png`. On the server you store the original images in `large` and you create a copy in `small` by some rules downsampled by 4 with at least 320x320 and image quality 0.75. It should be enough such that you do not cause too much network traffic

Comment: From a user experience perspective I would not even try to push the images themselves to the user. It would be enough for you to send a notification _New Content Uploaded/Available_ and if the user is interested in it, when he opens your application you pull the latest images

Comment: @RaduIonescu    i think the best way is to stop that my idea of sending some bytes through GCM and send the user a link. i have even discovered whatsapp do not send some bytes to the user. i thought they do so when they discover the user is connected to mobile network and not wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Image re sizing means you're going to shorten the resolution of the image. suppose user selects a 1000*1000 px image. you're going to convert the image into a 300*300 image. thus image size will be reduced.

And Image compression is lowering the file size of the image without compromising the resolution. Of course lowering file size will affect the quality of the image. There are many compression algorithm available which can reduce the file size without much affecting the image quality.

One handy way I found in here is :

```
    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("1024x768.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

Log.e("Original   dimensions", original.getWidth()+" "+original.getHeight());
Log.e("Compressed dimensions", decoded.getWidth()+" "+decoded.getHeight());
```

gives

> 12-07 17:43:36.333: E/Original   dimensions(278): 1024 768 12-07
>
> 17:43:36.333: E/Compressed dimensions(278): 1024 768

Comment: i want an compressed image with same size as original but of low quality. am trying to implement image sharing like whatsapp where if i send you an image, you will see how the image looks before downloading from the server. this means i have to send a low quality image to user where am thinking of doing so using google's GCM **which does not allow data load of more than 4kb**

Comment: well in that case why not try this : http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getSquareCropDimensionForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int dimension;
    //If the bitmap is wider than it is tall
    //use the height as the square crop dimension
    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight())
    {
        dimension = bitmap.getHeight();
    }
    //If the bitmap is taller than it is wide
    //use the width as the square crop dimension
    else
    {
        dimension = bitmap.getWidth();
    }

return  dimension;
}
```

int dimension = getSquareCropDimensionForBitmap(bitmap);

```
        System.out.println("before cropped height " + bitmap.getHeight() + "and width: " + bitmap.getWidth());
        Bitmap croppedBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, dimension, dimension);
        System.out.println("after cropped height "+croppedBitmap.getHeight() +"and width: " + croppedBitmap.getWidth());
```

it can crop and can reduce size u can specify ur own size

Comment: i will give it a try and give you response

Comment: for my case, the above solution was able to reduce quality but **number of bytes were still large** so i ended up using `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,10,outputStream)` which was ok with me